# How to config apache for a local network app?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, networking, lamp, intranet

Hey guys I'm really new to this please forgive me if I butcher all the terminology. I've managed to get a lamp-server running for my small business and have created a small webapp that runs on the server. How do configure apache to only allow other devices in the same network to connect and restrict access for everyone else? Is what I'm trying to achieve called an Intranet server? If so what are the security aspect I should be aware of?

Thanks in advance! I'm looking forward to learn from you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache can be easily configured to do what you want.  You have a few options.  First you could tell Apache to only listen to local intranet IPs.  If you can't do that, you can configure Apache to restrict access: [Apache Access Control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html)